# After `DELETE VERTEX v;` how do I reset the RecordId?

Tags: orientdb, database, nosql

After executing `DELETE VERTEX v;` to delete all records from an oriendb database, how do I reset the RecordId (@rid) to start over?

I want to run tests so after deleting all records I seed records again; I test a particular record #13:3 but then it changes after the tear down. It is not #13:3 when the db is seeded again.

Comment: Hi Karim, are you looking for a OSQL command that resets the `@rid` class everytime you remove all records (for example restart  from #9:0), right ?

Comment: yes that is what i am looking for @LucaS

Comment: Hi Karim, I've just answered. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created this simple structure to try your case:

```
create property V.id integer

create vertex V set id = 1
create vertex V set id = 2
create vertex V set id = 3
create vertex V set id = 4
create vertex V set id = 5
```

Now the class V has this rids and records:

```
select from V

----+----+------+----
#   |@RID|@CLASS|id
----+----+------+----
0   |#9:0|V     |1
1   |#9:1|V     |2
2   |#9:2|V     |3
3   |#9:3|V     |4
4   |#9:4|V     |5
----+----+------+----
```

but if you execute the command

```
truncate class V unsafe

Truncated 5 record(s) in 0,016000 sec(s).
```

all records in class V will be deleted (instead of deleting them manually) and the `@rids` will be resetted. Now, if you execute a new `create vertex V set id = 1` command, the `@rid #9:0` will be re-assigned to the first re-inserted record. The following is an example of re-insert:

```
create vertex V set id = 1

Created vertex 'V#9:0{id:1} v1' in 0,015000 sec(s).
```

Now, if you query the class V, you'll see the `@rid #9:0` re-assigned

```
select from V

----+----+------+----
#   |@RID|@CLASS|id
----+----+------+----
0   |#9:0|V     |1
----+----+------+----
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a bunch! this helped! however I had to use `TRUNCATE CLASS V POLYMORPHISM UNSAFE` and then also `TRUNCATE CLASS E POLYMORPHISM UNSAFE` for its edges. This is only for unit tests, to teardown db changes, not encouraged for production

Comment: Hi Karim, thank you. In my example I used class V but you're free to use the command on every class you want.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to delete all Vertexes not a particular class. All classes are V so thats why I have to use POLYMORPHISM